# Jquery or php get all html from string and rebuild

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Yes, that is right I think. I have a string which contains html output, and I need to filter the text and the object html from that string, translate, and then rebuild it.

Example:

```
My email address is <a href="mailto:bla@bla.com">bla@bla.com</a> And I want you to email me.
```

So what I need from this string is:

1. My email address is
2. bla@bla.com
3. And I want you to email me.

So basically I want to split and have everything in an object or array. I also need to know which ones are text and which ones are html.

so output should be something like this:

```
$arr[0] = Array("text" => "My email address is", "type" => "text");
$obj[1] = Array("text" => "<a href="mailto:bla@bla.com">bla@bla.com</a>", "type" => "text");
$obj[2] = Array("text" => "And I want you to email me.", "type" => "text");
```

This way I can translate everything and return it.

Now I know to use and how to use preg_split, but this is an example. The html can differ from an , 
,  and all other html objects. So is preg_split the best way to go or is there another better way. Cause the initial text gets pushed from jquery. And I don't mind looping it through with some ajax calls.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it cleared my html. It can differ from all kinds of html, not js.

Comment: Do you want to do this in Javascript or PHP?

Comment: Does not matter. The Bing translator does both. 
I'd never thought id say it, but bing has a better product then google. And it also free (up to a point).

Comment: Okay - thanks.  But I was asking about the question of splitting the text.  I see that you have some answers now anyway.

Answer (score 2):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/fWGNW/3/)**

Try this

### code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = new Array();
    gettext($('div'));

    function gettext(ele) {
        $(ele).contents().each(function () {

            if (this.nodeValue == null) {

                gettext(this);

            } else {
                obj.push(this.nodeValue); // pushing to array
                alert(this.nodeValue)

            }

        });

    }

});
```

### html

```
<div>My email address is <a href="mailto:bla@bla.com">bla@bla.com</a> And I want you to email me.</div>
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much for your fiddle. Works great! But I made a  boo boo, I should have said the content came from a textarea. So this solution, although great, does not work as is. 
I've been "fiddleing" around with it, and I don't think I can get this to work. The output the content() gives is "&lt;" and "&gt;", which does not register as a node. I can't seem to convert it either. I've updated the fiddle. I'd be greatly thankfull if you could take a look at it: http://jsfiddle.net/fWGNW/4/

Comment: Ha, i've got it. I've putten everything in a temporary div whilst writing it from ".text()" first. So:
$('#tempdiv').html($('#pushback').text());
gettext($('#tempdiv'));

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net, which lets you turn your DOM strings into actual HTML DOM structures, for extracting data from in a sensible (not-string-manipulation) way.

Comment: This looks very promising too. I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, i'm definitely putting this in my bookmarks. I have another project which requires scraping. This will be great :)